# svn as backup system on ubuntu: what about new added files?

Tags: svn, ubuntu, backup

I'm using a svn repository for the backup of specific folders of my server.

I'm using cron to commit the changes regularly.

However, I was just wondering if it takes in consideration new added files as well. Or just the changes to **existing** files.

If so, what should I do ? Abandon the idea to use svn for backups ?

Comment: Subversion is not a backup tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cronjob might do the following before committing:

```
cd /working-copy
svn status | grep ^\? | awk '{print $2}' | xargs svn add
```

This approach only works, if you're not interested what's going to be added, though. It'll add **all** new files.

**EDIT:** "Edwin Buck" pointed out that `svn status` only lists new directories, not their files. `svn add` adds a new directory recursively (including files), though.

Comment: @goreSplatter I actually just need a safe copy, I don't need all previous incremental changes.

Comment: @Patrick Why are you using Subversion, then? Wouldn't rsync fit your purpose better, if you're not interested in the incremental changes?

Comment: @goreSplatter Because I know a good service providing 2 gb free space for each project. I don't find any free backup service for multiple projects on the same machine with 2gb free space per project.

Comment: One more question: is your code line getting all files recursively ?

Comment: @Patrick Yep. `svn status` lists *all* files new to the repo with a prefix question mark (`?`).

Comment: @goreSplatter Technically, svn status will only list all new immediate files with a prefix question mark, so a directory won't show it's sub-files.  However, you're still right as adding a directory will recursively add all the sub-files and sub-directories in that directory at that time.

Comment: @Edwin Buck Thanks. I was implying that. Thanks for pointing that out.